# MySQL left join not using index

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

I'm stuck for a while with indexes issues... I have two tables:

products :

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
+----+
```

products_relations

```
+------------+-----------------+----------+
| product_id | product_link_id | priority |
+------------+-----------------+----------+
|       4084 |            3554 |        1 |
|       8515 |            6680 |        1 |
|       4084 |            1248 |        2 |
+------------+-----------------+----------+
```

When I run this query

```
SELECT 
  `products`.*,
  products_relations.product_link_id 
FROM
  `products` 
  LEFT JOIN products_relations 
    ON products_relations.product_id = `products`.id
```

Indexes are not used:

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table              | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | products           | NULL       | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 5790 |   100.00 | Using index                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | products_relations | NULL       | ALL   | product_id    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |    4 |   100.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Why ?

Here is my schema, if you want to try it.

I've simplified it a lot to make it more readable, but the index issue is still here.

```
CREATE TABLE `products_relations` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_link_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `priority` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

ALTER TABLE `products_relations`
  ADD KEY `product_id` (`product_id`);


CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


ALTER TABLE `products`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);


ALTER TABLE `products`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: how many records are in products_relations table? if the table is small index is not used.

Comment: It actually has 4 records, but there is another left JOIN (not represented here) table with hundred of thousands of records. 
I wasn't aware that small tables could not use indexes.

Comment: the query engine is smart enough to grab the 4 records first then join it on the bigger table, hence no need to use the index, if you want to better test this at a few hundred records and run explain again https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-scan-avoidance.html

Comment: Your premise is that using index = performance. That's wrong. Index is used to reduce amount of records that have to be read from disk / memory. You have only 4 records, it's kind of pointless to read the index and then look at 4 records. Index would make this slower and doesn't help. With low amounts of records or if index cardinality is low, MySQL will (correctly) disregard the index. Reason: index won't help it do less work, hence it's useless.

Comment: So my problem is somewhere else. I'll make another question showing my whole schema and the performance issue I'm facing. You probably can answer this question and I'll close it. Thanks!